# Обращение по UNC пути к локальному файлу Windows

Tags: windows

Подскажите, есть ли деградация по производительности, и, идет ли нагрузка на сеть, если к локальному файлу обращаться по UNC пути? Или винда понимает, что это loopback?

Например:
На сервере **MYSERVER** открываю файл c:\Share\report.xlsx по его сетевому пути \\**MYSERVER**\Share\report.xlsx

Comment: Многое зависит от реализации чтения-записи файла: последовательно, с буферизацией и т.д. 1-й вариант: прямое обращение к файлу идёт дисковую подсистему. 2-й вариант: UNC-путь- обращение к файл-сервису, который является абстракцией над той же дисковой подсистемой. Т.е. в последнем случае возникают накладные расходы. Но при некоторых условиях файл-сервис может ускорить работу с файлом: кеширование, блокировки и прочее. Отсюда, производительность зависит конкретных условиях эксплуатации. И не понятно, что считать деградацией по отношению 1 варианта к 2-му: большее потребление памяти, CPU, etc.

Comment: Реализация чтения - открытия файла COM Excel. 
Деградация - снижение производительности выполнения операции, в данном случае открытия файла.

Answer (score 0):

Доступ к локальному файлу по пути универсального соглашения об именовании (UNC) не должен приводить к снижению производительности или создавать дополнительную нагрузку на сеть. Windows предназначена для распознавания таких путей и соответствующим образом обработает запрос.